# Can't solve Extremely Long Time to First Byte on Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress

I have a site I am helping someone with. The site loads incredibly slow. I have tried using Cloudflare CDN, I have optimized images, I have adjusted the caching, I have contacted their hosting company and nothing seems to help.

The website URL is www.vintagevermilion.com

I have ran several speed tests and found that the time to first byte is about 22 seconds. In looking at the waterfall it is the actual website's DOM that is taking this long. I cannot determine why it is taking this long.

Comment: My first guess would be that it's the server config or server itself, second guess is that it's the plugins/page builders that are being used.  It takes a full 6 seconds when I tested for the first 'auto optimized' script to load - kinda defeats the purpose of optimizing them.  What speed test utility did you use? Also, try installing Query Monitor and seeing if that flags anything for you.  It's in the WP Plugin Repository.

Comment: I used GtMetrix for the speed test. I did take your advice on Query Monitor but didn't find anything specific. I agree that the optimization seems ineffective. I cannot figure out why it is so slow for these things.

Comment: Just upload a plain text file or simple "Hello World" html and try to access it. If these plain and simple assets are also slow, that means it is a routing / server problem and no code can save you.

Comment: @KevinSwanberg: I've just tried to access the site. The speed seems reasonable (response within 1s, first content draw within 2s). The [PageSpeed insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vintagevermilion.com) can be improved but not as bad as your 22s experience.

Comment: Have you check the speed after log out?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it... ...if it was something you did, you can post an answer to your own question and accept it, so people looking in the future can have something to try if they're experiencing the same problem.  Also, I'm super curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply to this. I did fix this through a series of experiments and small common sense changes. Essentially, this web page was built and maintained by a series of interns with no web experience over several years, meaning that there are a ton of terrible things about this site.

I added in a caching plugin, removed several superfluous and unnecessary plugins that went unused, and also removed some pointless lines of Javascript. Additionally, I found that Tripadvisor's widget extends load time ridiculously for some reason, so removed that.

Ultimately, the page uses a very inefficent page builder plugin that still saps the speed. I am scrapping and redesigning the site from scratch.